# Safari stops working when attached to a corporate network

Tags: network, safari, mojave, proxy

My work MBP is in a corporate network which has heavy security. For the last few months Safari has been driving me crazy. It will work for a period of time, then just stop. No matter what web page I ask for (Public like Google or StackOverFlow, or the companies own confluence or other servers) the blue progress bar goes to around 10-15% then just stops. The web page never loads, never times out. Just nothing.

Chrome doesn't have the same problems. But I'd rather use Safari. I'm guessing this could be an issue with the corporate proxies, but I don't know how to debug it. Sometimes restarting Safari gets it working again for a while, sometimes I have to restart the machine to get it back. Am on Mojave.

Any advice? Corporate IT has no idea even though there's hundreds of Macbooks in here now.

Answer (score 1):

> Corporate IT has no idea even though there's hundreds of MacBooks in
>   here now.

I'm not sure how you came to that conclusion because setting a policy like "blocking Safari" wouldn't be something that decided on by rank-and-file employees; IT management knows.

There are security products on the market that go well beyond [deep packet inspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_packet_inspection) where IT can can use analytics and heuristics to determine what software you're using and block it. Since it seems to take Safari a few moments to stop working, this sounds most plausible.

> Any advice?

Yes.  Talk to IT.  Ask them why they allow Chrome and block Safari (there may be a valid reason for it.)

Comment: They've said they aren't blocking Safari which is why I'm thinking the proxies. Plus Safari will work for a while, then it just stops.

Comment: If they have a proxy, then it's under their control as well.  A browser just works, if it get's blocked at the network level, there's nothing we can do.  Does Safari work outside their network (like at home)?